# Google Autocomplete in angular directive not working on mobile safari

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, safari, angularjs-directive, google-places-api

I have an angular directive that listens for a google place 'place_changed' event. The code works just fine in desktop browsers.

However, it doesn't work on mobile safari in iOS7 (haven't tested older versions). Tapping a location doesn't seem to be firing the place_changed event and the input field doesn't get populated with the location value.

Is there some other event I should be triggering, listening for?

```
angular.module('app').directive('googlePlace', function (Location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, element, attributes, model) {

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], {types: ['(cities)']});
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {



                    if (autocomplete.getPlace()){
                        var googlePlace = autocomplete.getPlace();
                        $scope.googlePlace = googlePlace;
                        Location.setGooglePlace(googlePlace);

                        var location = googlePlace.address_components[0].long_name + ', ';
                        if (googlePlace.address_components.length === 2) {
                            location = location + googlePlace.address_components[1].long_name;
                        } else if (googlePlace.address_components.length === 3) {
                            location = location + googlePlace.address_components[2].long_name;
                        } else if (googlePlace.address_components[3].short_name === 'US') {
                            location = location + googlePlace.address_components[2].short_name;
                        } else {
                            location = location + googlePlace.address_components[3].long_name;
                        }

                        $scope.displayLocation = location;

                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                model.$setViewValue($scope.displayLocation);
                                model.$setValidity(element.name, true);
                                element.val($scope.displayLocation);
                            }, 100);

                        });
                    } else {
                        $scope.googlePlace = null;
                        $scope.displayLocation = null;
                        model.$setViewValue($scope.displayLocation);
                        model.$setValidity(element.name, true);
                        element.val($scope.displayLocation);
                    }

                });


            element.on('blur', function () {

                setTimeout(function(){
                    if (attributes.required && !$scope.googlePlace){
                        model.$setValidity(element.name, false);
                    } else if (element.val() && !$scope.googlePlace){
                        model.$setValidity(element.name, false);
                    } else if (!element.val()){
                        Location.setGooglePlace(null);
                        model.$setValidity(element.name, true);
                    } else{
                        model.$setViewValue($scope.displayLocation);
                        model.$setValidity(element.name, true);
                        element.val($scope.displayLocation);
                    }
                }, 300); // this seems to matter even though 0
            });


            element.on('keypress', function (e) {
                $scope.googlePlace = null;
                Location.setGooglePlace(null);

                if (e.which === 13) {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed');
                }

            });

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem.. Have you solved in some way? Thanks.

Comment: this was awhile ago - I think I had to disable fastclick for that directive. Def. worth looking in to.

Comment: safari - the new IE!